# create a new column that shows the sum of more columns in R

Tags: r

I would like to add a new column, which is the sum of SINGLE, COMP2, COMP3, COMP4, COMP5. How should I handle the NA and 0?

```
SINGLE COMP2 COMP3 COMP4 COMP5
1      NA    NA     0     0     0
2      NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
3       8     1     2    NA    NA
4      NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
5      NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
6       3     2     5    NA    NA
7      NA    NA     2     0     0
8      10     2     1     0     0
9      NA    NA     0     0     0
10      0     0     0     0     0
```

..    ...   ...   ...   ...   ...

Comment: Probably just `rowSums(df, na.rm = TRUE)`? Also, what do you mean by handling the `0`s?

Comment: `df$sum <- rowSums(df, na.rm = TRUE)`